# Passing parameters to python from VBA

Tags: python, vba, excel

In VBA code, I am calling Python and passing an argument successfully like this when there are no spaces in the path to the python file:

```
Dim wsh As Object
Set wsh = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

Dim shell_exec As Object
Set shell_exec = wsh.Exec("C:\path_to_executable\python.exe " & "C:\path_without_spaces\file.py " & arg)
```

However, I cannot find any way to pass an argument to python when the path to the python file contains spaces.  For example, triple double-quoting the path works when there is no argument:

```
Set shell_exec = wsh.Exec("C:\path_to_executable\python.exe " & """C:\path with spaces\file.py""")
```

But I am unable to find any way to pass an argument when doing this.  For example, calls like this (and every variation on this theme I can think of) fail:

```
Set shell_exec = wsh.Exec("C:\path_to_executable\python.exe " & """C:\path with spaces\file.py """ & arg)
```

Is this possible, or is the use of spaces fatally ambiguous in this situation?

Advice is appreciated.

Comment: You might be able to use Windows file associations and skip the part about the path to `python.exe`

Comment: @JohnColeman: Interesting. How could I do this while using the shell? It insists on a path to an executable as a argument.

Comment: I'm not sure how to use it from VBScript -- but it can work from the command prompt.

Comment: The `Run` method seems easier to use with arguments with spaces. I'm not sure why.

Comment: Thanks. I was using Exec to pass a result from Python to VBA through StdOut. Do you know how to do this with Run?

Comment: It seems to be a bit of a bug since *exactly* the same string will work with `Run` but fail with `Exec`. How badly do you need to have spaces in the path? Personally, I keep most of my programs in a folder in my documents (in a path which contains spaces) but also keep a folder close to the root directory for programs that I need to invoke from the command line (which isn't a very common use-case for me). You could create such a folder and move a copy of your script to it.

Comment: @JohnColeman: Thanks. I was thinking of doing just that. Existing path names have spaces in them (for which I will curse MS for all time) and I was hoping to accommodate current circumstances and not introduce any new procedural requirements for others. Seems to be a choice between spaces in path names and being able to pass a return value through StdOut.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use multiple quotes:

```
Set shell_exec = wsh.Exec("""C:\path_to_executable\python.exe """ & """C:\path with spaces\file.py """ & arg)
```

Comment: Thanks, hadn't tried that one, but no success. This causes the terminal window to stay open, which is different, but the argument is still not passed.